# how to place object relative to parent at x distance specified

Tags: unity, c#, transformation, coordinates, hierarchy

**My application:**

Place furnitures or construction objects (doors/windows) in scene.

Everything is fine until I touch the construction objects. Since the application is mobile, it will be hard for a user to place the door at the exact place, so I decided to help and put a little menu where they can specify where to put it:

[image: Placement dialog]

The scene (room in this case) looks like this:
[image: Top-down view of room]

**Some implementation details:**

The walls are a prefab instantiated 4 times:

```
 GameObject wall_N = Instantiate(wallPrefab);
 wall_N.gameObject.name = "Wall_N";
 wall_N.GetComponent<Transform>().position = new Vector3(center_W, 50, center_H + z / 2);
 wall_N.transform.SetParent(room.transform, false);
 wall_N.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = myColor;
 wall_N.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
```

and so on for each wall.  `x, y, z` are the values introduced by user and transformed into int

`int x = Int32.Parse(xInput); // width int z = Int32.Parse(zInput); // length int y = Int32.Parse(yInput); // height`

and `Center_W` and `Center_H` are screen points:

`private int center_W = Screen.width / 2;  // 960  private int center_H = Screen.height / 2; // 540`

In the above image i've introduced  `x, y, z` as `200, 200, 200`

**Question:**

In what coordinates must I work in order to place the door at a dimension specified?  I'm not even sure if this approach is correct, the main idea is to put the door at the correct position in the room.

[image]

**What I've tried**

The first idea that came in my mind was to find the `bottom-left` coordinates from `Wall_N` and place the door at `point + A` but then I realised that the `bottom-left` is represented in different coordination sistem then `A`. I've search about it and I tried to see the values from `screenPoint` in different coordinates:

```
var screenPoint = new Vector3(center_W, 50, center_H + z / 2);

 var worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
 var screenToViewport = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(screenPoint);
 var viewpointToWold = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
 var worldToViewport = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(screenPoint);
        
 Debug.Log("wallN - screen point " + screenPoint + " to worldPos " + worldPos);
 Debug.Log("wallN - screen point " + screenPoint + " to viewPortPos " + screenToViewport);
 Debug.Log("wallN - viewPort " + screenPoint + " to worldPoint " + viewpointToWold);
 Debug.Log("wallN - world " + screenPoint + " to viewport " + worldToViewport);
```

Unfortunately, they didn't tell me anything, I just don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score -1):

After many tries I found that the dimensions introduced are calculated in pixels

`int x = Int32.Parse(xInput); // width
 int z = Int32.Parse(zInput); // length
 int y = Int32.Parse(yInput); // height`

`wall_N.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(x, y, 0);` -> if I introduce 200, x will be 200 pixels, y introduced will be in pixels etc relative to this position `wall_N.GetComponent<Transform>().position = new Vector3(center_W, 50, center_H + z / 2);`

So, after a bit of thinking I've come to this formula:

`var xDistance = center_W - DimensionIntroduced/2 + dimDesiredFromWall_V + xDoorDimension/2;
// or var xDistance = center_W + DimensionIntroduced/2 + dimDesiredFromWall_V + xDoorDimension/2; if i want to move at right`

`var yDistance = center_W + DimensionIntroduced.height/2`

`var clone = Instantiate(newGameObject, new Vector3(xDistance, 0, yDistance), Quaternion.identity);`

So I guess that `transform.localScale` is measured in pixels, but i'm not very sure, as long as it works as expected in my app, it's ok xD
I don't know how much it helps tho, but if somone has questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Is this solution valid for multiple resolutions?

Comment: It should be...

Comment: This information is not correct. Unity transform positions are measured in parent/world units, not pixels, and the pixel size will depend on how they are positioned/oriented relative to the camera, the camera's size/fov, and the resolution of the output display/window. `localScale` is a *multiplier* on size, so setting `localScale` to 2 will make the object twice as large as it was originally on that axis.